# Deploying an WebAPI project (including swagger) into Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, aws-serverless

I know that the Azure function supports HTTP trigger and we can write a function that can be exposed like an API.  I'm looking for an option to host a complete C# WebAPI project (multiple Rest endpoints including swagger definition) into a single Azure function.

Is this feasible? and supported? I see this scenario is completely supported in AWS Lambda.  Where we can deploy a whole WebAPI project into a single lambda.  Here is the demo of
[the](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DiQMrH9HF_s) same.

Answer (score 1):

I have watched the provided Video and I observed the same functionality is also available in Azure Functions.

As Direct way is not available like publishing the Web API to the Functions but [migration of Web API to Functions](https://edi.wang/post/2020/7/7/migrating-an-aspnet-core-web-api-project-to-azure-function) is possible if the Web API is authenticated with any option like Open API, etc and using the APIM Service we can manage all the operations in it.

And as per the Microsoft Update, `Startup.cs`and `program.cs` is unified to the `program.cs` file. So, I have added the required swagger configuration code in the file `program.cs` and tested it, working successful locally.

[image]

Another approach is you can call the Web APIs from Azure Functions securely, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72204406) is one of my approaches along with few other ways to do it.

Refer to @*VovaBilyachat* alternative [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61927363) on publishing .NET Core Web API to Azure that provides the glimpse of using Containers instead Functions.